# $.param.querystring is not a function

Tags: php, jquery, yii

Firstly I wanna display data from table through `cgridview` in yii with pagination and default records per page is 20.

Here I wanna select the user the number of records per page as they need by providing select box like `5`,`10`,`20`,`50` records per page

Here's my code:

```
CHtml::dropDownList('pageSize',$pageSize,array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,50=>50,100=>100),
    array('class'=>'adm-srchdrp','style'=>'padding:2px;height:26px;width:95px','prompt'=>'PageSize',
    'onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiGridView.update('family-record-grid',
    {
        type:'POST',
        url:$(this).attr('href'),
        data:{pageSize:this.value },
        success:function(data) {
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('family-record-grid');
        }
    })"
));
```

Here 
`family-record-grid` is the id of `cgridview` and 
the problem is when I select the custom `pagesize` from the select box it raises the error:

> `$.param.querystring is not function`

in the console. I have checked that all the JS files are loading properly say `jquery.ba-bbq.js` and `jquery.yiigridview.js`.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: suggestions please

Comment: Any one is there...Please Help me

Answer (score 3):

I guess you was upgraded your jquery. I was changed this line

```
     options.url = $.param.querystring(url[0], params);
```

to

```
     options.url +="?"+ options.data;
```

I was by passed jquery's old code with a worked one.

Comment: what was the jquery version that ,please mention . or shall i change the line to as you suggested in yiigridview.js

Comment: hi @rch,
I was changed the line because it was caused other errors when i was upgraded jquery. I guess it because yii1 components depended on old jquery versions.